# Is ICANN planning any changes to domain registration soon?

Tags: domains

The BBC is [reporting](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-11720728) that domain registration will be changing next year.

> The .co
>   landgrab could be one of the last
>   before ICANN overhauls the way net
>   addresses are assigned.
>
> Next year the body is due to open up
>   the system so that companies and
>   individuals can register any name they
>   want.

I haven't heard anything about a change—is the BBC correct, and if so, what are the details?

Comment: I have no idea about it but the one thing is fact that BBC revealed about. The more info about the ICANN and the strategies for applying name and numbers, can check out here: www.icann.org/ . My Domain registrar has doesn't inform me about this type of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The expansion of the generic top-level
>   domain (gTLD) space will allow for a
>   greater degree of innovation and
>   choice.

[New gTLD Program (ICANN.org)](http://www.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtld-program.htm)

This program will let anyone with enough money (and a reasonable claim to their own gTLD) to open up a new [gTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) - definitely big news (though it has been [in the works for a couple years](http://www.crn.com.au/News/115066,icann-proposes-greater-top-level-domain-name-flexibility.aspx) now).

Comment: Thanks! So it's not as big a difference as BBC implied—I thought they were getting rid of registration requirements.